# Custom validator not invoked when fields are empty

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have implemented a custom validator for my screen referring to the example given [here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html).

But in my case, my validator method is not invoked if I don't enter any values in any of the field. So the check for empty fields is never done. The required messages are displayed everytime.

If I removed the required attributes, even in that case the validator is invoked only if the fields have some value in them. How do I get all my validations to be done in the validator class?

My xhtml:

```
 <h:form>
                <p:messages id="message" closable="true"/>  
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="changePassPanel"> 
                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd0" value="Current password :" />  
                    <p:password id="pwd0" value="#{homeBean.password1}">                            
                        <f:validator validatorId="PasswordValidator"></f:validator>
                        <f:attribute name="pwd1" value="#{pwd1}" />
                        <f:attribute name="pwd2" value="#{pwd2}" />
                    </p:password> 

                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="New password :" />  
                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{homeBean.password2}" binding="#{pwd1}"/> 

                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Confirm new password :" />  
                    <p:password id="pwd2"  binding="#{pwd2}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>  
                <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save"  validateClient="true"/>  
            </h:form>
```

Comment: Do you have `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` set to `false` in `web.xml` or so?

Comment: Okay. Are you using Mojarra or MyFaces? MyFaces defaults to `false` when JSR303 bean validation isn't available. In any way, try explicitly setting it with value of `true`.

Comment: @BalusC No luck. If I remove required= true from all my fields, it never reaches the validator. If i have required=true for pwd0, and submit without entering any value, I get the validation error on the screen(still doesn't invoke the validator method). Only if I enter a value in pwd0, and submit it does it invoke the validator method. I want it to invoke the validator first in all cases.